# Different results from Firebug and html file

Tags: firebug

This's just a short question. I test some code with html file and command line of Firebug:

```
console.log(typeof myName);
var myName = “Julia”;
```

I show me 2 different results. `undefined` for html file.

I will update it a little bit. For firebug.First times I run it. It show me `undefined`. Once again, It give `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare myname first and then call it, as it is executed once and you call it again it return string for the second time and undefined for the first time.

```
console.log(typeof myName);
var myName = “Julia”;
```

it returns undefined.

```
 var myName = “Julia”;
console.log(typeof myName);
```

It returns string

Answer (score 0):

console.log(typeof myName);
should come after 
var myName = “Julia”;

```
var myName = “Julia”;
console.log(typeof myName);
```